# How to optimize my if statements or make less if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(varName1 <= 1 && varName1 > 0)
{
$('#id1').addClass('ClassName');
}

if(varName2 <= 2 && varName2 > 1)
{
$('#id1').addClass('ClassName');
$('#id2').addClass('ClassName');
}


if(varName3 <= 3 && varName2 > 2)
{
$('#id1').addClass('ClassName');
$('#id2').addClass('ClassName');
$('#id3').addClass('ClassName');
}
```

So basically I am wondering if there is a better way to do this with less if statements(8 total with same pattern).

Comment: `varName1`? `varName2`? `id3`? `id1`? `ClassName`? ***ARGH!***

Comment: I think you may have meant `varName3` in the third if-clause rather than `varName2`?

Comment: Please give a serious example rather than this convoluted and confusing example. This may well be a sign of poor design in the rest of the system, not just here.

Comment: I think this was a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
   if(varName[x] <= x && varName[x] > (x-1)) {
      $('#id[x]').addClass('ClassName');
   }
}
```

Comment: You should note that this depends on turning `varName*` into an array; also your `'#id[x]'` should be `'#' + id[x]` or `'#id' + x` (numerical IDs, a bad idea in general), I think? What about adding the lower IDs? His code adds the class to #id1 and #id2 if varName3 is suitable, too.

Comment: This code works because I needed all the subsequent ids to have the class as well.

Answer (score 2):

Combine your selectors in one statement

```
if(varName1 <= 1 && varName1 > 0)
{
  $('#id1').addClass('ClassName');
}
if(varName2 <= 2 && varName2 > 1)
{
  $('#id1,#id2').addClass('ClassName');
}
if(varName3 <= 3 && varName2 > 2)
{
  $('#id1,#id2,#id3').addClass('ClassName');
}
```

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Else if has been added for better code readability.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: No! In this case, if varName value falls into the first if condition, the remaining 2 wont be executed. so i guess else if is a better candidate here.

Comment: Very well, I shall demonstrate a case in which your code has a different effect: `varName1 = 1, varName2 = 2`. His code will add the class to #id1 and then to #id1 and #id2, your code will add it to #id1 only and then not add it to #id2.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan : Ah! I did not notice the varName2. Thought about only varName1. Your comment make sense. Will change my answer now. Thanks for jumping in.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate and best of way accomplishing the task is to replace your if-else-if with switch statement. You can use ternary also though it doesn't make a big difference except the code size would be reduced

switch( var ){
   case 1:
       $('#id1').addClass('ClassName');
       break;

```
case 2:
    $('#id1,#id2').addClass('ClassName');
    break;

case 3:
      $('#id1,#id2,#id3').addClass('ClassName');
      break;

default:
     break;
```

}

Note in switch case if you want to execute all use cases the you should omit the break statement. Here this code snippet will execute just the specific use case and when it encounters the unmatched case it breaks and comes out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0, $id;
while(i <= 3) {
    if(eval("varName" + i) <= i && eval("varName" + i) > (i - 1)) {
        $id = $("#id" + i).addClass("className");
    }
}

//But I recommend something like below (if that is your purpose):
$("div").each(function(_i, _self) {
    var $self = $(_self);
    if($self.hasClass("className")) {
        $self.addClass("className");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way of doing this is to use hashmap or array lookup which wouldn't require if statement.

```
function getClassName( id ){
    var cssClassMap = {0: "aClassName", 1: "bClassName", 2: "dClassName", 3: "eClassName"};
    var cssClassName = cssClassMap[id];

   return ( cssClassName !== undefined ) ? cssClassName : "not-found";
}

$("id"+varName).addClass( getClassName( varName ) );
```

**Tests on Chrome JS Console Below**
[image]